# Magento 2 - Disable some modules per store view

Tags: magento2, module, admin, layout, magento2.2

I have setup two stores in Magento 2.2.6, each store have their own theme and url address.

In one store I have Porto theme installed in the second store I have other theme.

How I can disable for example Porto theme / modules in the second store?

Thank you

Comment: I guess its closed because M1 answer from Marius is also correct for M2.

Comment: but where you have System->configuration->Advanced->Advanced to turn off modules in M2 for example?

Comment: As far as I know these options do not exist in M2. I think you have to add config options fur your modules. However, vote to reopen.

Comment: @Robert , though I vote for reopen but same answer applies for magento 2 as well

Comment: thank you @MurtuzaZabuawala maybe someone will have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Magento 2.2.* Now Advanced Menu is no longer available. You cant got those options from Configuration.

> The ability to disable module output has been removed from Admin.  You
>   disabled module output from Admin in a previous release of 2.0.x and
>   2.1.x, Now you must manually configure these settings from app/etc/config.php file.

So Unless the module comes with an enable/disable setting that can be set per store view this is to my knowledge not something Magento provides as an out of the box capability.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this. It is by no means the "right" way to controle module output per store view but I could not find anything else that worked, app >  etc > config.php:

```
<?php
if(getenv('HTTP_HOST')) {
    switch(getenv('HTTP_HOST')) {
        case 'dev1.domain.com':
        case 'staging1.domain.com':
            return [
                'modules' => [
                      'Magento_EXAMPLE1' => 1,
                      'Magento_EXAMPLE2' => 1,
                      'Magento_EXAMPLE3' => 1,
                      'Magento_EXAMPLE4' => 0,            
                  ]
            ];
            break;


        case 'dev2.domain.com':
        case 'staging2.domain.com':
            return [
                    'modules' => [
                      'Magento_EXAMPLE1' => 1,
                      'Magento_EXAMPLE2' => 0,
                      'Magento_EXAMPLE3' => 1,
                      'Magento_EXAMPLE4' => 0,            
                  ]
            ];
            break;
    }
} else {
    return [
        'modules' => [
            'Magento_EXAMPLE1' => 1,
            'Magento_EXAMPLE2' => 1,
            'Magento_EXAMPLE3' => 1,
            'Magento_EXAMPLE4' => 1,            
        ]
    ];
}
```

It runs the else on any php bin/magento commands and runs the switch on renders, works with Varnish, ElasticSearch5 and Redis the way it is configured on our servers.