# Magento 2.3.4 - Disable module for specific store view

Tags: magento2

As the headline says I'm trying to disable a specific module for two out of our three store views. The module itself doesn't have an on/off, and all changes happens globally regardless of the store view the change is made in. Can anybody help with this? I cannot find any guides that are up to date and works for Magento 2.3

EDIT:
To be specific it's a module for an online invoicing system, and they just have one module for magento. As it is now the module creates invoices for all orders from all stores, and it should only create invoices for one store, as the other two stores are owned by another company.

I've tried Bryan Bielefeldt's suggestion on: [Magento 2 - Disable some modules per store view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245029/magento-2-disable-some-modules-per-store-view) however, it didn't stop the module from working in the backend.

Comment: I would contact the module developer, it would be fairly easy to extend the module and add some logic to only perform actions based on store view.

Answer (score 0):

Open store configurations

Then choose a store you need to disable that from the drop-down of the top.

Then enable or disable the module you need.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to disable modules in the backend on Magento 2.3

Comment: No you dont need to disable. Isn't there any module options to deactivate it ?

Comment: Nope :-( the module doesn't have that possibility, and I have no alternative module. I think the only way would be to insert code into the module and/or Magento, but I'm not qualified to write code.

Comment: I think that module not compatible with multi-stores then. It's better if you can find a module which supports multi-stores

Comment: There's just this one module. To be specific it's a module for an online invoicing system, and they just have one module for magento. As it is now the module creates invoices for all orders from all stores, and it should only create invoices for one store, as the other two stores are owned by another company.